# File system not responsive for short time after boot

Tags: 16.04, boot, hard-drive, filesystem

my question concerns Ubuntu 16.04.

After every boot I can view my folders and files on my HDD as intended.
After 1 min of proper usage the file system becomes unresponsive for around 25 seconds. Then it works fine again infinitely.

How can I reach to the source of this issue? Any suggestions?

Just tell me if I should add any more information regarding my setup.

Comment: Sounds like an `@reboot` cronjob to me. Have you tried _System Monitor_? The _Processes_ tab has various _disk_ columns (r/w). Perhaps you can see there which process does the disk I/O.

Comment: What is the output of dmesg command

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **:-)** What is the output of `sudo smartctl --all /dev/sda` If `sudo: smartctl: command not found` type `sudo apt install smartmontools` and try again.

Comment: Thank you all for your quick answers! With the help of @PerlDuck I saw that megasync required a lot of disk space. And this is already the cause for the unresponsiveness: It seems like my cloud sync program has to initialize (check) all corresponding directories. Guess I cannot solve it, I just have to be patient after a boot :)

Comment: You _may_ have a look at [`ionice`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ionice). It can throttle a program's I/O greediness so that other processes aren't affected too much.